# Manual Test Results by Build?

Tags: azure-devops

I have all my test cases in Azure Devops Test Plans and now I'm executing them manually against a build.

How do I view manual test results by build?

I can view and filter test results by build  on the "Runs" page but I would prefer to see test results grouped by build not filtered to a single build.

Any options for this?

I had hoped the the Test Plans - Progress Report would provide this but I don't see a way.

Maybe there is a way to group all my manual tests executions into a Test Run?

Answer (score 0):

I researched and attempted with the related Azure DevOps REST API and Azure CLI, however, I did not find any available way.

It seems that we can only directly filter the test results to the build run level, and cannot to the build pipeline level.

Maybe, you can indirectly get the associated build pipeline via the following way:

- Use the REST API "[**Runs - Query**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to list the test runs associated with a specified build pipeline.
- Use the REST API "[**Results - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" in a loop to list the test results of each test run.